# How to extract a Inno Setup Installer

Tags: extract

How to extract a [Inno Setup Installer](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). This is not a `.7z`, or any other file that `7z` can extract. according to the file command this is a file of the type:

- `PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows`

And `exiftool` says this:

```
............                    : ..........
Comments                        : This installation was built with Inno Setup.
............                    : ..........
File Description                : Package for Universal Extractor
```

How Do I extract this?

Comment: @Serg InnoSetup installation programs cannot be opened or read with the 7z utility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [innoextract [image: Install innoextract]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=innoextract) to extract the contents of an InnoSetup installation program. Once installed, the application can be run as follows:

```
innoextract setup-something-1.0.0.exe
```

Note that files are extracted to the current directory.

Comment: I was looking for this! I couldn't find it for 15.10! Will try to install to somehow...

Comment: @blade19899 it's [available for 15.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/innoextract).

Comment: I just find out  I was `apt-cache search` **innounp**,  the cmd Windows version of Inno Setup Installer... Doh.